# How to implement oauth login in flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-authentication

How to implement OAuth with Google in a flutter from scratch. and any special permission required for Google OAuth implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dependency in pubspec.yaml file.

```
firebase_auth:
  cloud_firestore:
  firebase_core:
  google_sign_in:
```

Follow the registration steps of https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in

main.dart

```
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("signed in " + user.displayName + "  " + user.email);
    setState(() {
      textprint=user.displayName +","+user.email;
      urlImage=user.photoUrl;
    });
    return user;
  }
```

After completing the above task generate the release apk and test it.